# Site-to-Site - Subnet routed to azure firewall but rules are being ignored

Tags: azure, site-to-site-vpn

I configured a Site-to-Site connection between my Azure VNet and On-Premise firewall.

The connection is working just fine but I'm trying to control the Site-to-Site connection on my Azure Firewall.

I created a route that configures the subnet next hop as my Azure Firewall, I can tell it's working because my VM with the same subnet & route receives my firewall public IP.

Now, I'm trying to control some rules to deny traffic in my Site-to-Site connection but anything I configure on the Azure Firewall side seems to be ignored on the Site-to-Site connection..

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Did you test if your IPs/subnet that you apply rules for is actually getting properly routed ?

Comment: Yes, when I apply the route table I created for the subnet, I get my firewall public IP on the VM so it seems to apply.